# SAXParserFactory как им пользоваться

Tags: java, android, xml

вот предположим у меня есть xml файл в проекте андроид.

```
<people>
<name>denis</name>
<name>ivan</name>
</people>
<people>
<name>bobic</name>
<name>sharick</name>
</people>
```

мне нужно по нажатию клавиши выводить на экран парно два слова(например, "bobic  sharick")  как это сделать?

P.S. я не разобрался сам с тем как использовать SAX. ребят, мне нужен код, а не ссылка на обучающие материалы. там для примеров парсинга  приводят сложные структуры xml с кучей разных тегов  без объяснений кода. Вроде: "вот пример, все и так понятно" Пожалуйста очень нужно.

Comment: pavlofff это понятно. я привел пример xml. как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос у вас неконкретный, непонятно как именно вы хотите выводить данные и почему именно "bobic sharick" должно выводиться, а не "denis ivan".